# set date format string as d/M/yyyy and htmlencode=false in programmatically created gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, date-format

MyDataSource is a datasource stored in a session passed through a search page

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    gridview1.DataSource = Session["MyDataSource"];
    gridview1.DataBind();




}
```

gridview1 is a gridview with no datasource waiting for the page load event to bind it to a datasource, in my case it is MyDataSource

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" 
    BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" 
    GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" 
        HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FAFAE7" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DAC09E" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E1DB9C" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#C2A47B" />
</asp:GridView>
```

dates appearing in this gridview display as M/d/yyyy + time
for example 12/31/2010 00:00:00

My Question: i need a way to display date as d/M/yyyy with no time for example
31/12/2010
usually i do this by setting the gridview properties htmlencode=false and dateformatstring="{0:M-dd-yyyy}"
but in this case the gridview dont show any field because it bind data only at run time

please i need your help in this issue ASAP.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" 
BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" 
GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
<FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" 
    HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FAFAE7" />
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DAC09E" />
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E1DB9C" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#C2A47B" />

<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PropertyName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PropertyName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DateTimeProperty" DataFormatString="{0:dd/M/yyyy}" />
</Columns>
```

It works fine in my computer. Hope it will help you.

Best regards,
Dima.

Comment: Dima, it worked fine with me but with no header. can you please instruct me how to add the header

Comment: @mokokamello: asp:BoundField has a property to set the header. I believe its "HeaderText"

Comment: Dima and Pandincus: thanks to you both, you are great and helpful, nice meeting you on StackOverFlow

Comment: @Dima: one more question: now the columns are duplicated for example i have one DateOfBirth = 31/12/1980 and another DateOfBirth = 31/12/1980 00:00:00 in the same gridview, do you suggest a solution

Comment: @mokokamello did you set AutoGenerateColumns="false"? if didn't, set it and set list of columns by yourself using <asp:BoundField DataField="PropertyName"/>

Comment: great, it worked fine with me, thanks Dima and thanks again Pandincus

Answer (score 2):

The gridview won't show any data unless you tell it what to show.

A quick fix would be something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gridview1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="dateLabel" runat="server" />
            <ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and then in your code-behind:

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.DataItem != null)
    {
        var item = (MyCustomDataBoundObject)e.Row.DataItem;
        var dateLabel = (Label)gridview1.FindControl("dateLabel");
        dateLabel.Text = item.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
}
```

The above is untested, but should be enough to get you what you're asking.

Out of curiosity, why are you passing the datasource through the session? I don't know anything about your app, but it's never an approach I've taken before. Why not just bind the gridview to an objectdatasource which you've defined in your aspx page? Then you could use a simple bound column.

Comment: hi Pandincus, i am still new to asp.net and C# and i may have made a mistake putting datasource in a session, i will consider your suggestion. i have 2 questions: 1- i am not sure what to put instead of MyCustomDataBoundObject, should i replace with gridview? 2- i have 3 different dates in my gridview: date of birth, date start and date end.. i am not sure if your code will handle three dates

Comment: @mokokamello: Nevermind, you can do what Dima suggested. I don't know why but for some reason I thought the databound columns wouldn't work with a datasource declared in the page_load event.

Comment: @mokokamello: But if you wanted to follow my code, you would replace (MyCustomDataBoundObject) with whatever you were pulling out of your datasource. I don't know what that is because I don't know what your datasource is doing. And to handle 3 dates you'd create 3 template fields. But as I said, the easiest solution would be Dima's solution below.